# How to avoid violation of constraints for insert and Updates in Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle

I am building a web application. which inserts records in database. I validate records before inserting them in database. If between the time of my validation check and insertion, another application put the db state such that a unique key violation constraints occur if I attempt to insert these records that I have just validated for insertion. How can I avoid this kind of problem. I am using an oracle database and my development language is java.

Comment: you can use locks.

Comment: If another records inserts the row , what do you want the current thread to do with that row ? Discard the data ? Update the data ? A lot depends on that. You can use locks , may be use a flag to insert row with the key , clear it when you feel the record is not good or insert it if you find it good. Have the other thread look at the flag before insert or update.

Comment: Catch the exception and handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't unless you change your constraints. You have several ways to to:

1. You keep the unique constraint and deal with the database exception in your Java code. Race conditions can happen and you have to deal with it.
2. You lock the entire table as soon as someone enters "insertion mode" in your app, effectively limiting inserts to one at a time. This would mean blocking other users in your application from entering edit mode until the first one is done. Probably not a good idea, but can work when you have very few users.
3. Remove the constraint. Now this might seem difficult but think about it. Do you really need globally unique entries in some fields? Or can you work around that by including an additional column in your key. This could be an artificial counter, effectively making each row unique again or maybe just the UserID, so that the unique constraint is only checked within each user?